# will adding metal nano particles to a CNT-polymer matrix increase the conductivity of the polymer?

Tags: metal, conductivity, nanotechnology, carbon-family

I was wondering would just physical mixing of metal nano powders with MWCNT in a polymer matrix improve the conductivity of the said polymer? Would the metal particles interact with the CNT network. I see some papers where they chemically reduce the nanoparticles while mixing them with a CNT dispersion improving conductivity. But I was wondering if would just physical mixing of powders result in a similar increase?